# How to active enterprise policies in Tor Browser 9.0?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, windows, firefox

How do I create active enterprise policies for Tor Browser 9.0 on Windows?

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your policies should be the same as Firefox of the same version. However if you are not able to connect, then you should review your firewall rules. More details can be found in the [FAQ](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en).

Answer (score 0):

It's better to avoid it because they can be used to fingerprint you, but if you do need some customization **and** keep privacy - use a QubesOS's disposable VM's with all the customizations you need